# How to create a function groupBy, which groups elements of a list into tuples of lists and a value based on a function given as input?

Tags: functional-programming, elm

I have to implement a method named *groupBy* which has the following signature:
`groupBy : (a -> b) -> List a -> List ( b, List a )`.

The method takes as input a function and a list of items and returns a list of tuples in the form (b, List a), i.e. it returns some kind of dictionary in which the **key** is the value **b** of the function applied to an item **a** in the input list, and the **value** is an array of items for which the function applied on has the same value. The function given as a parameter is the *criteria* by which the elements are *grouped by*. The following examples should make it more clear.

It should return the following results for the give tests:

- `groupBy .x [ { x = 1 } ] --> [(1, [{x = 1}])]`
- `groupBy (modBy 10) [ 11, 12, 21, 22 ] --> [(1, [11, 21]), (2, [12, 22])]`
- `groupBy identity [] --> []`.

I'm not sure what the 'identity' input means, but I suppose that it is an input for which the method should return the same array which was given as the second parameter.

I've tried the following code and I almost managed to get the result, but I'm stuck and I have no ideas of how I should continue:

```
groupBy : (a -> b) -> List a -> List ( b, List a )
groupBy criteria list =
    let
        unique lst = 
            List.foldl
                (\a uniques ->
                    if List.member a uniques then
                        uniques
                    else
                        uniques ++ [a]
                )
                [] 
                lst
        keys = 
            list
                |> List.map criteria
                |> unique
        pairs =
            List.map2 Tuple.pair (List.map criteria list) list

        filtered_list =
            List.filterMap (\x -> criteria x == keys) 
        group kl lst =
            case kl of
                [] -> []
                k::ks ->
                    (k, []):: (result els)
    in
        []
    -- Debug.todo "Implement groupBy in Util.elm"
```

If I run the following code in **elm repl**:
`List.map2 Tuple.pair (List.map (modBy 10) [ 11, 12, 21, 22 ]) [ 11, 12, 21, 22 ]`, then I get the result:
`[(1,11),(2,12),(1,21),(2,22)]`

The **unique** function returns a list of unique elements (basically a set) given a list which contains duplicates.
The **pairs** function creates tuples of (**b**, **a**) form, but I'm trying to get to the form (**b**, List **a**).
The other two functions don't work, they're just attempts for trying to get to the final form.

[[How do I ask and answer homework questions?]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: Please see [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [ask] more generally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function already exists in the `list-extra` package under the name `gatherEqualsBy`. You can check the implementation there: https://github.com/elm-community/list-extra/blob/8.7.0/src/List/Extra.elm#L2132

You can use https://klaftertief.github.io/elm-search/ to search for signatures:  `(a -> b) -> List a -> List ( b, List a )` in your case.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution to my previous question:

```
groupBy : (a -> b) -> List a -> List ( b, List a )
groupBy criteria list =
    let
        unique lst = 
            List.foldl
                (\a uniques ->
                    if List.member a uniques then
                        uniques
                    else
                        uniques ++ [a]
                )
                [] 
                lst
        keys = 
            list
                |> List.map criteria
                |> unique
        
        group kl lst =
            case kl of
                [] -> []
                k::ks ->
                    (k, List.filter (\x -> criteria x == k) lst) :: group ks lst
    in
        group keys list
```

I used *unique* for making sure all the keys are unique (keys are computed applying the function *criteria* from the input parameters to all elements from the *list* input parameter, and then removing the duplicates).
Next, looped trough all the keys and filtered the input list, so I would only have a list of elements on which if I apply the *criteria*, the result is equal to the current key *k*. In the end, I created a tuple (**k**, [**e**]) | **e** = *criteria*(**a**), a in *list*, and appended it to the final result, which is  list.